# Python variables in SQL Update query

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm very new to Python and I'm facing a problem with Python-SQLite connection.

```
con=connection()
cur=con.cursor()
cur.execute("""UPDATE table1 SET column1=%s WHERE column2=%d""",(var1,var2))
if(cur.rowcount > 1):
    cur.commit()
else:
    return["Error"]
```

Where `var1` stores a string, and `var2` stores an integer.

The error is the following:

> SQLError('SQLError: near "%": syntax error',)

I've read plenty of tutorials and threads in here about how to write my query with the variables and I'm in a dead end.

Answer (score 6):

According to the sqlite [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) you want to use ? for your variable. Example:

```
cur.execute("""update table1 set column1=? where column2=?""", (var1, var2))
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
mycursor.execute("UPDATE table SET column WHERE name = '%s' AND age = %s" % ("Alex", 30)
```

When passing in a string.

> Use quotes

And at the end of the execute statement, use

> %

Keep in mind that if you will pass multiple variables you have to put them inside a tuple

***Took me a long time just to understand that you have to have the % at the end when writing an UPDATE query***